# Android - Menu items not showing as they should

Tags: android, menu

I want to include a menu in my activity, now it has just one item for help with an icon and a text, the showAsAction is set to ifRoom but it is always shown in the action overflow. Why I don't get juste the drawable?

Here is the xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.mycompany.myapp.Mymainclass" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/help"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

The MainActivity:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Menu menu;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle save){
        super.onCreate(save);
        setContentView(R.layout.pokemons_layout);
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            if (save != null) {
                return;
            }
            CustomListFragment listFragment = new CustomListFragment();
            listFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, listFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        this.menu = menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        String bytearray = Base64.encodeToString(DB.bytearray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        prefs.edit().putString("BYTEARRAY", bytearray).apply();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        String bytearray = prefs.getString("BYTEARRAY", Base64.encodeToString(DB.bytearray, Base64.DEFAULT));
        DB.bytearray = Base64.decode(bytearray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

Comment: change it to "always"

Comment: also remove the orderInCategory item

Comment: then it will work with ifroom

Comment: orderInCategory is the priority of item

Comment: I did it, is showing in the action overflow,  and without the Icon !

Comment: did you remove orderInCategory ?

Comment: Yes, I did all you told me to do

Comment: remove the context in the parent and re-try

Comment: Not working... Maybe there is a problem with the icon? It is not showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87646/discussion-between-roman-panaget-and-prakhar).

Comment: <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/help"
            android:title="@string/help"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this because not all apps use the appcompat support lib

```
  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_add_size"
    android:title="@string/menu_add_item"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
 </menu>
```

Comment: I want the icon to appear in the action bar. With this I have a string in the action overflow

Comment: can you show you main activity i dont see any problem in your layout xml

Comment: try deleting xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" line and change this line app:showAsAction="ifRoom" to android:showAsAction="ifRoom"

Comment: Tried it out. Exactly same result: string in the action overflow and no icon

Comment: @RomanPanaget Please Try to use      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" instead of app:showAsAction="ifRoom"

Comment: WORKED ! However, Android Studio recommends me to use "myapp" instead of android because of an appcompat stuff

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct, please edit it with the comments changes or make a reference to the comments